# My long furred cat was recently groomed and it's revealed lots of dandruff, is that normal?

Tags: cats, grooming, skin-condition

My non-pedigree cat was long furred, and our wonderful groomer cut it right back. He didn't seem stressed at all, and is walking around with a confident tail.

[image: white cat with fully shaved torso and clipped hind and front upper legs]

But what I noticed was a significant amount of dander on his shaved parts. Since then it's mostly dropped off, but I wanted to check if this was a normal occurrence post-shave?

Here is a close up of what remaining dandruff I could get off him ~2 hours after his clipping was finished. This is a lot lot less than my first stroke of his fur.

[image: a close up finger showing small flecks of dander]

My main concern is if the dander returns or if it was simply hidden by the fur? I don't know if he needs a skin ointment to replace the natural protective oils he would have had in his fur.

Is this normal, and do I need to take any precautions?

Answer (score 1):

"Normal" as in "happens frequently" - yes.

"Normal" as in "no health concern" - maybe.

Cats (from personal observations) generally get visible amount of dandruff when they get overweight and have hard time self-grooming all of their fur. Other mobility issues also contribute.

Otherwise, one can't see anything loose over the skin because it gets systematically licked away.

Answer (score 0):

Your cat may have lots of dandruff due to a poor quality diet, sometimes the wrong fatty oils you feed your cat may cause dry skin, thus leading to a unhealthy amount of dandruff. Your cat may also have Ringworm Infection, Ringworm infection causes red patches that are itchy, but in some cases, it could cause dry skin and dandruff, you may need to brush the cats hair regularly or you can change her diet to a high quality wet food for your cat. The source for this is from All About Cats

Comment: Could you please add a link or explain what "All About Cats" is? This site has users worldwide and for example I do not know if it is a show, a website or a book...